# Travis error for @available command in iOS

Tags: ios, travis-ci, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I am running an issue with Travis and Fastlane (Gym) and I haven't found a way of fixing it.

I added a new dependency through Cocoapods and all works fine in my device but when I run it through Travis it encounters the following errors:

`no known class method for selector 'labelColor'`
`no known class method for selector 'systemBackgroundColor'`
`no known class method for selector 'secondarySystemBackgroundColor'`

In these places, there's an @available macro because they don't exist in iOS versions under 13.

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        return [UIColor labelColor];
    } else if ([self isDarkColor:[self getBackgroundColor:config]]) {
        return [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
```

So why is it failing in Travis? And how to avoid it?

What I did now is to define Xcode11.1 in the `yaml` file, but this hasn't fixed the issue yet. Is there a way I can specify to run it only for iOS 13?

I added the following and still fails:

```
osx_image: xcode11.1
language: objective-c
xcode_destination: platform=iOS Simulator,OS=13,name=iPhone X
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a typo in your `yaml` file.

[Per the travis documentation for Xcode 11](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2019-10-10-xcode-images-available):

```
os_image: xcode11.1
```

Remove the **x** from the value that you posted.

Comment: You can use both, right? https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/osx/#macos-version

Comment: Is this in your yaml file: `os: osx`?